# How to include whitespaces in string replace?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I need to replace strings like '5 hours' with '5h'. But I'm only able to get it to '5 h'. How to remove the space in between? When I replace the "hours" in my function to " hours" with a whitespace, it replaces nothing and returns '5 hours'.

```
$('div.block_name span').text(function(){
    return $(this).text().replace("hours","h");
});
```

Comment: Show your HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex like so:

```js
// "\s?" means that find a space only if it exists
console.log("5 hours".replace(/\s?hours/, 'h')); // 5h
console.log("5hours".replace(/\s?hours/, 'h')); // 5h
```

Comment: This solution also works with non-breaking spaces (`&nbsp;`), which get translated to unicode character 160 by jQuery's `text()` method. I believe that's what the OP's issue was.

Comment: Yeah! Thanks for the regex method. I tried using it earlier but was using the putting quotes around it. Btw, jquery just made the world look easier for me. (just started using it today!)

Comment: @VaishMK I would suggest not using jquery.  You can use DOM node `.textContent`

Comment: But happy to help! :-)

Comment: Is using the DOM node directly, faster than with the jQuery wrapper?

Comment: Most definitely.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('div.block_name span').text(function(){
                    return $(this).text().replace(" hours","h");
                });
```

This will replace the leading whitespace as well as the string `hours` with the string `h`.

Working JSFiddle Example: https://jsfiddle.net/4bqz79vh/

Comment: Just tested on this fiddle and it works as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/4bqz79vh/

Comment: The regex solution should work. If there is a non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`) in the HTML markup, it gets translated to unicode character 160 instead of a standard space.